# How to use parent element attribute value in child element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to propagate parent element attribute value to child elements in angular? In the example case, mydiv directive could read the e-vertical value (either true or false) and act accordingly.

This somewhat works (edit: it does not work), but is it correct? E.g. the angular-way.

HTML:

```
<form e-vertical="true">
   <div mydiv></div>
</form>
```

Parent element attribute directive

```
mod.directive('eVertical', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    scope: {
      eVertical: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      return ctrl.eVertical = scope.eVertical;
    }
  };
});
```

Child element

```
mod.directive('mydiv', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    template: '<div do-vertical-stuff="eVertical"></div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      return ctrl.eVertical = scope.eVertical;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Post your question in javascript - not many of us know coffeescript. Also, can you be more specific on the issue? Which attribute are you attempting to read in the child element or rather what is your expectation here?